# Filter StylePropTypes according to component type

Tags: react-native

I'm not experienced js developer so may be I'm asking about something obvious.

Imagine I create component (let's name it `MyInput`) which consists from `TextInput` and a `label`.
Where `label` - `string` (which renders into `Text`) or any other React component.
Component's `style` prop is used for `TextInput` customization. So I add possibility to set `labelStyle` prop which will be used by `label`.

When I use `MyInput` I want to do such thing: if `label` is text (no matter raw string or already a `Text`) - apply to it `color` and `fontSize`.
But if I pass instead of string some other component, let's say `Image` - then **do not** apply unsupported parameters.

Right now react-native warn me every time when I try to apply `fontSize` or other style props to non-text components.

I know, warnings can be switched off, but for me hiding the problem != solution.

Ideally I would like to have some method or class or whatever which will look at style props and on supported props by component and somehow filter them before apply.

Am I missing something? Or this warnings are okay?

Comment: Just don't. Warnings are there to help you not to ship poor code. Fix all of them, you're good. Create your component in the way it don't throw warning in dev, they won't in production. Beside, are you willing to check all those style props in production (and possibly decrease performance)?

Comment: @Andreyco actually react-native performs such checks under the hood. This is the reason of getting those warnings. I just want to do something similar so there shouldn't be significant decrease of performance. The question is - how to correctly perform it.

Comment: React Native does that in development environment only.

Comment: @Andreyco Yes you are right, but that doesn't mean that such check is unnecessary. I'm looking for the solution of problem and not reasons to ignore it.